# tr tag lost when retrieving div element

Tags: jquery, html

I have ajax POST method where I'm working with a response html from a FreeMarker template(addNewRow.ftl). The response html consists of two div elements- one containing the table row data and other containing validation errors.

When appending the table row to the table body, the tr tag is missing - resulting in an incorrect display. I'm currently trying to pass the data wrapped around a dummy table tag to see if that resolves the problem. In the meantime I'd appreciate any guidance.

html code

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input value="R1C1"></td>
      <td><input value="R1C2"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

js code

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //to simulate the ajax request
    var html = '<div id="mainDiv"><tr>\
   <td>\<input value="R2C1">\</td>\
   <td>\<input value="R2C2">\</td>\
</tr></div><div id="errDiv">error Test</div>';

    var obj = $('table')
    $.post('/echo/html/', {
        html: html
    }, function (template) {
        console.log(template);
        var mainDiv = $(template).filter('#mainDiv');
        console.log(mainDiv);
        var errDiv = $(template).filter('#errDiv');
        console.log(errDiv);
        obj.find('tbody').append(mainDiv);

        obj.find('tbody').before(errDiv);
    }, 'html');
})
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmaitipe/yLj994oj/)

Comment: Here is a simplified example of the scenario.
https://jsfiddle.net/rmaitipe/yLj994oj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that ended up working for me is to wrap a table tag around the tr html and then later extract the tr html from the div element.